# Advanced Squid Log Analysis

Tags: logging, squid

We are currently using sarg to analyse our squid proxy logs, while it works ok, its not really amazing and we could do with a bit more information. The main thing we would like to do is be able to give a manager a restricted view of what his staff have been up to, broken down by time (i.e. its ok to go on shopping sites at dinner, but not at 9:30am)

We dont mind paying if the software is good and well supported, but free is better!

Answer (score 0):

The squid proxy log isn't really designed with giving you the type of detailed user activity logging your thinking of. Yes you can use Sarg to get a general idea as to user cache activity and traffic. However it will never give you the kind of granular detail your manager wants.

I would recommend trying LightSquid it provides more detailed reports then sarg if configured correctly.